# Couldn't see anything on ubuntu!

Tags: graphics, radeon, display-resolution, amd-graphics

Things that happens:
I install windows 10 dual booted with ubuntu, windows 10 graphic seems to be fine, after I install ubuntu. When I boot the system, my TV said "Mode not supported, This resolution is not supported" and 2 mins later, ubuntu splash screen pops up, after reboot. Everthing is black and "mode not supported" again..

Info:
Graphic card: Radeon HD 3400 Series or something

- dual booted
- ubuntu 17.04
- using DVI-I to Hdmi adapter on graphic card
- 6 GB ram
- Intel core 2 duo

Answers will be appreciated :D

Comment: ubuntu is trying to use a screen resolution that your tv doesn't support. I believe the recovery option has a failsafe mode so you can boot up and change the video resolution.

Comment: Ater bios post, I couldnt even access grub or whatever. What would I do?

Comment: do you have a live CD or flash drive?

Comment: Yes i did have it. And I reset system once already

Comment: you have to set the grub graphic mode. if your installer has a reovery mode, open a shell into your install and edit /etc/default/grub : uncomment this line `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` or this line `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console`  (remove the #),  then update grub.

Comment: @ravery As I said, I couldn't access anything. It just a black screen and my monitor doesn't supports its resolution.